# Convert 'x hrs y min z sec' to seconds

Tags: excel, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

a) So I have a huge folder of .csv data with a column about time duration where the cells are 'x min y sec' (e.g. 15 min 29 sec) or 'x hrs y min z sec' (e.g. 1 hrs 48 min 28 sec). The cells are formatted by text.

I want to batch change them to the number of seconds, but I have no idea where to start. I can't get the data in another format.

I thought about somehow using 'hrs', 'min' or 'sec' as delimiters, but I don't know how to move from there. I also thought about using ' ' as delimiters, but then the first column is filled with either hours or minutes depending on the time duration.

I also thought about using PostgreSQL's `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '5 days 3 hours')`, but I haven't been able to work out how to use this on a column from a table.

b) Is there a better way to change this time format 'Fri Mar 14 11:29:27 EST 2014' to epoch time? Right now I'm thinking of using macros in Excel to get rid of 'Fri' and 'EST', then put the columns back together, then use the to_timestamp function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is this on Windows or some version of Unix?  You talk about Excel and it is tagged "unix-timestamp".

Comment: Is the data in a PostgreSQL table or in a CSV file?

Comment: This is on OSX. The data is in CSV files, but I'm importing it later to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM column_name::interval)
FROM my_table;
```

The `interval` can use the regular time units (like `hour`), abbreviations thereof (`hr`) and plurals (`hours`). I am not sure about a combination of plural and abbreviation (`hrs`) though. If that does not work, `UPDATE` the column and `replace()` the sub-string "hrs" to "hours".

If you want to save the number of seconds in your table, then you convert the above statement into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE my_table SET seconds_column = extract(epoch FROM column_name::interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Excel if you have data in only those 2 formats and starting from `A2` you can use this formula in `B2` copied down to get the number of seconds:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("hrs",A2)-1)*3600,0)+SUM(MID(0&A2,FIND({"min","sec"},0&A2)-3,2)*{60,1})`

It finds the relevant text then gets the number in front for each and multiplies by the relevant number to get seconds

Answer (score 1):

I would split with space as the delimiter, then examine the second column.  If it contains the string "hrs", then your seconds answer is:

3600 * column 1 + 60 * column 3 + column 5

Otherwise it is:

60 * column 1 + column 3